# Can I get a collection of object extending a class and implementing an interface?

Tags: java

There's not much to add to my question, basically:

```
class A {}
interface I {}

// how can I get a Set<> of object of type A that implements I?
```

I tried a few things `<A & I>`, `<A extends I>`, `<? super A extends I>` and a few other but didn't find anything that works, so I'm wondering if this is possible at all. If it isn't I'm curious about the reasoning behind it.

Thanks

Comment: Are A and I actual class and interface names, or do they represent generic type parameters?

Comment: Looks like same issue as here: [Multiple restrictions on generic type based on super and sub classes in java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085557/multiple-restrictions-on-generic-type-based-on-super-and-sub-classes-in-java

Comment: John is right, it looks like I can't have one such collection without making the enclosing class generic too, that's unfortunate :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support intersection types, it only supports multiple bounds (as in `extends A & I`) when declaring type parameters. That is, we can not use a notation like `A & I` to denote the family of types that extend both A and I, but we can declare a type parameter `<T extends A & I>` to refer to a *specific* such type.

If the latter is what you want, a type parameter is a great fit. But if your collection should admit unrelated subtypes of `A` and `I`, no nice solutions seem to exist. My best idea is a hack like:

```
class AISetWrapper {
    Set<A> set = new HashSet<>();

    <T extends A & I> Set<T> getSet() {
        return (Set<T>) set; // unchecked cast that only works because generics are not reified
    }
}
```

which would allow us to write:

```
class AI1 extends A implements I { }

class AI2 extends A implements I { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AISetWrapper aiSet = new AISetWrapper();
    aiSet.get().add(new AI1()); // compiles
    aiSet.get().add(new AI2()); // compiles
    aiSet.get().add(new A()); // does not compile
    aiSet.get().add(new I() {}); // does not compile
}
```

Comment: Seems that `class AISetWrapper<T extends A & I>` would avoid the unchecked cast.

Comment: That is what my answer calls the type parameter approach. As I already said in my answer, that approach restricts all elements of the collection to a *specific* common supertype that extends A and I. That is, you could not add instances of AI1 and AI2 to the same collection.

Comment: My point is that in the `hack` solution, moving the generic declaration to the class level instead of the method level would remove the cast warning.

Comment: I got that. But doing that would change the meaning, as my comment tries to explain ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make A implement I:

```
interface I {}
class A implements I {}

Set<A> setOfA;
```

Possible is alsp

```
class SubA extends A implements I { }
Set <SubA> setOfSubA;
```

Usage of a class A cannot make it change it's behaviour, as would be indicated by its sudden "implmentation" of I. Where should the implementations of the interface methods come from?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do the following:

```
public class MyClass<T extends String & Iterable>{
    private Set<T> mySet;
}
```

And

```
public <T extends String & Iterable> void myFancyMethod(Set<T> mySet){}
```

However when I did

```
private Set<? extends String & Iterable>
```

I got a compile error of `Syntax error on token "&"`. Seems that you can do the `&` syntax when declaring a type `<T>` but not for wildcards `<? ...>`.

A better discussion of this can be found at: [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class:

```
public class MySet<E extends A & I> extends HashSet<E> {
    // blank
}
```

This will simply ensure that any instances of `MySet` will contain only objects that extend `A` and implement `I`.

Comment: Sorry typo I accidentally wrote `implements` instead of `&`. Just fixed it.

Comment: Should be `HashSet<E>`. However, this limits the OP to a single implementation of `Set`.

Answer (score -1):

```
// how can I get a Set<> of object of type A that implements I?
```

You cannot guarantee both in a single generic statement. You can do something like

```
public void addToSet(I iInstance) {
   if(iInstance instanceof A){  
   //logic to add to your set
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the `Set<?>`, please?

Comment: Since you want your object to both extend `A` and implement `I` you can use either as generics.

Comment: But the above does not put compile-time restrictions that the passed object extend A AND implement I, just one or the other. The point here is compile-time checking because as run-time you can do whatever you want via type-erasure.

Comment: question is about getting set of objects which extend A and implemnt I. It mentions nothing about compile time or run time. Yes objects not suiting the criteria(just implementing I) may compile while adding to the set via above mentioned function but they will not actually be added as the inner check will fail.